# Only return results from first table with two joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 3 tables. I need to get lastname, firstname, and employee number from the first table and name from another table.

In order for me to get the name on table s there needs to be a match between the slsrep columns on table s and table sw.

The issues is that I only want to return the rows from the first table (p). There is only 700 records in the first table but it is pulling 900.

Basically, I just want to look at each row in the table p and match the name from table s.

This is what I currently have:

```
SELECT p.LastName,
       p.FirstName,
       p.EmpNo,
       s.Name
FROM   PDDA..PhoneDirectory p
       LEFT OUTER JOIN nxtsql..swsmsn sw
            ON  p.EmpNo = sw.EmpNo
       JOIN NxtSQL..SMSN s
            ON  sw.slsrep = s.slsrep
WHERE  sw.statustype = 1
ORDER BY
       p.LastName
```

Comment: `LEFT OUTER JOIN` should be just `JOIN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this.   One is to use a sub-select to get s.Name:

```
SELECT p.LastName, p.FirstName, p.EmpNo, (
  SELECT TOP 1 s.Name 
  FROM NxtSQL..SMSN s 
  INNER JOIN nxtsql..swsmsn sw 
    ON sw.slsrep = s.slsrep
  WHERE p.EmpNo = sw.EmpNo
  AND sw.statustype = 1
) AS Name
FROM PDDA..PhoneDirectory p
ORDER By p.LastName
```